# I'm trying to add points in gnuplot using a second dat file but they aren't showing up on the graph

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to add points where an author has contributed to a project using gitstats data. I have parsed it out of the html file so it gets into a .dat file that looks like

```
2011-04-27 5000
2012-02-04 5000
2011-05-03 5000
2013-08-24 5000
2012-10-29 5000
```

Then I want to use gnuplot to plot both the overall LoC with the date points added to show when an author has started working on a project. The gnuplot file looks like

```
set terminal png transparent size 1080,640
set size 1.0,1.0

set output 'lines_of_code.png'
unset key
set yrange [0:]
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d"
set grid y
set ylabel "Lines"
set xtics rotate
set bmargin 6
plot 'lines_of_code.dat' using 1:2 w lines, 'authordata.dat' using 1:2 w points
```

but my graph doesn't show the authordata.dat points. I'm fairly certain it's something with how I'm trying to add the second .dat file but googling hasn't been helpful thus far.

Comment: How does the `authordata.dat` file look like? You are using the wrong format for parsing your data file. `set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"`. And both data files must use the same time format (unless you're using gnuplot 5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue thanks to christoph's comment. Both files need to be using seconds from 1970 01 01 or dates. Thanks